# If a business cofounder leaves for a better opportunity, does he still get a share of profit ?

Tags: india

Background:

We run a sports club in India which is about 9-months old firm. It makes less than 10Lakhs per annum and is yet to be registered as a private or partnership firm. My partner informed me that he will be leaving to another country for a better opportunity and will not be able to come for another year or two. Currently we have a 50-50 revenue sharing informal agreement since we know each other for many years. He is fine with a 75-25, but my father suggests we reach an agreement and close our deal paying him some money. I am puzzled and wonder how others handle this scenario. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am not a lawyer, but it looks to me like amicably agreeing 75-25 seems like a good deal. It does depend on how much he has input (and other things), but not having to fight over the deal might be worth something.

Comment: So he leaves the country, and for the next 30 years you work your ass off and turn the company into a billion dollar business. Do you think 25% is fair?

Answer (score 2):

### Legal Issues

In general, it is better to agree on how to deal with the removal of a partner *before* it comes up, however, you didn't so here you are.

At this point, there are no legal issues here: whatever you and your partner can negotiate and agree on will be perfectly legal - whatever it is, you should document it. Legal issues will only arise if you cannot agree - then you will have a dispute and, if you cannot resolve it, you may end up in court. I will not hazard a guess on what a court will decide: in theory, they will try to determine, based on whatever evidence is available, what you agreed about separation when you formed your partnership.

### The Business

I have no idea what your "sports club" involves and therefore to what extent it *is* an autonomous business and to what extent it is self-employment: that is, if you both stopped working in the business (perhaps engaging an employee), would it still generate revenue or is the revenue dependent on your personal efforts? Ideally, a business should be structured so that each of your draws a salary for the *work* you do and then split the *profits* left over. For example, if your sports club operates 7 soccer fields, 8 tennis courts and a clubhouse and employs 17 people then it is a business; if its just you two giving tennis lessons then you are self-employed.

The reason I mention it is that *part* of the *profits* that you take out are actually *wages* for the work you do and that he **wont** be doing.

### The Options

I prefer your father's suggestion over yours for the following reasons:

- What if his opportunity extends beyond 2 years? Will you be happy paying 25% for 5 years? Or 30 years?
- What if, by your efforts, you turn your business into a major enterprise and the revenues rise to hundreds of thousands? Are you still happy to share this 75/25?
- Alternatively, what if you want to abandon the business? Will your partner be happy for you to close the business?
- What if your partner (rightly or wrongly) thinks you are underreporting the income to reduce his share? How would that affect the relationship?

Better a clean break - you can put in place a mechanism for him to buy back in if you want at a fair and objective price when (if?) he comes back.